# HTML DOMDocument get string from tags following paragraph

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I want to parse html documents. I need the the contents of all 'p' after 'h2'.

The html to parse: (example)

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, 
</p>

<h2>Aenean commodo</h2>
<p>
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>

<h2>consectetuer adipiscing</h2>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, 
</p>
```

Here I want to get the last two 'p' tags (dynamically).

---

Here my PHP Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($html_file);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$h2_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');

foreach($h2_tags as $single_tag) {

     echo $single_tag->textContent;         
     print_r($single_tag);

}
```

This only gives me the text content of the h2. But I need the 'p' after the h2.
Is this possible or do I need to use an other class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($html_file);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodeList = $xpath->evaluate('//p[preceding::h2]/text()');

foreach ($nodeList as $domElement){
   echo $domElement->textContent."<br><br>";
}
```

Refer output: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7i5-3ir

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$items = array();

$document = new DOMDocument;
@$document->loadHTMLFile('example.html');

foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $node) {
    while ($node = $node->nextSibling) {
        if ($node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if ($node->nodeName == 'p') {
                $items[] = $node->textContent;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r($items);
```